# How to open specific activity via ID

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-room

I have a project with matches. In the project, I use the room database. I have three records in my database that have an ID and contain the fields imgTeamOne, imgTeamTwo, titleTeamOne, titleTeamTwo, itemDate. I have prepared a certain activity for each of the match (ActivityDetailOne, ActivityDetailTwo, ActivityDetailThree) and I want that when I clicked on the first card - ActivityDetailOne opened, when I clicked on the second card - ActivityDetailTwo opened, etc. How do I do this? How do I write a code so that a card with ID=0 opens ActivityDetailOne, please help. I'm a beginner and I don't understand

**FragmentMatch.kt**

```
class FragmentMatch : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var _binding: FragmentMatchBinding
    private val binding get() = _binding

    private val matchViewModel: ViewModelMatch by activityViewModels()

    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private var adapter: RecyclerAdapter? = RecyclerAdapter(emptyList())

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentMatchBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        recyclerView = binding.passRecyclerView
        recyclerView.layoutManager =
            LinearLayoutManager(activity, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter

        requireActivity().title = "Игры"
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        matchViewModel.matchListLiveData.observe(
            viewLifecycleOwner,
            Observer { receipts -> receipts?.let { updateUI(receipts) } }
        )
    }

    private fun updateUI(matches: List<MatchModel>) {
        if (matches.isEmpty()){
            initialDb()
        }
        adapter = RecyclerAdapter(matches)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    }

    private fun initialDb(){
        val match = MatchModel(UUID.randomUUID(), "25 сентября 2021", "Chelsea", "Manchester City")
        val match2 = MatchModel(UUID.randomUUID(), "25 сентября 2021", "Everton", "Norvich City")
        val match3 = MatchModel(UUID.randomUUID(), "25 сентября 2021", "Brentford", "Liverpool")
        matchViewModel.addMatch(match)
        matchViewModel.addMatch(match2)
        matchViewModel.addMatch(match3)
    }


    private inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView),
        View.OnClickListener {

        private lateinit var match: MatchModel

        private val titleTeamOne: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleTeamOne)
        private val imgTeamOne: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgTeamOne)
        private val titleTeamTwo: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleTeamTwo)
        private val imgTeamTwo: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgTeamTwo)
        private val dateGame: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dateGame)
        private val favBtn: Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.favBtn)
        private val btnDetail: Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnDetail)


        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        fun bind(match: MatchModel) {
            this.match = match
            titleTeamOne.text = (match.firstCommand)
            titleTeamTwo.text = (match.secondCommand)
            dateGame.text = (match.date)
            when (match.firstCommand) {
                "Everton" -> {
                    imgTeamOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_3)
                }
                "Brentford" -> {
                    imgTeamOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_4)
                }
                "Norwich" -> {
                    imgTeamOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_5)
                }
                "Liverpool" -> {
                    imgTeamOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_6)
                }
            }
            when (match.secondCommand) {
                "Everton" -> {
                    imgTeamTwo.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_3)
                }
                "Brentford" -> {
                    imgTeamTwo.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_4)
                }
                "Norwich" -> {
                    imgTeamTwo.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_5)
                }
                "Liverpool" -> {
                    imgTeamTwo.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_6)
                }
            }

            favBtn.setOnClickListener {
                val match = MatchModel(match.id, match.date, match.firstCommand, match.secondCommand, true)
                matchViewModel.saveMatch(match)
            }
            btnDetail.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(context, DetailActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        }

        override fun onClick(v: View) {
        }
    }

    private inner class RecyclerAdapter(private var matches: List<MatchModel>) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>() {
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(
            parent: ViewGroup,
            viewType: Int
        ): MyViewHolder {
            val itemView =
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_match, parent, false)
            return MyViewHolder(itemView)
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
            val match = matches[position]
            holder.bind(match)
        }

        override fun getItemCount() = matches.size
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would open a new field in the room db like "val type: Int" and check the type to open the new activity. But in my opinion you could create only one activity and make it generic for each match

Comment: After all, you can somehow make a check, if Id = 1 - open specific activity, or is it impossible?  I need to do just that

Comment: you can do like if (id == 1){
   startActivity(Intent(this, newActivity::class.java))
}

Comment: should I write this in my btnDetail.setOnClickListener ?

Comment: yep, when you click check the id and then call the activity you want

Answer (score 0):

Since I initially did not want to create a separate field in the database, and I used UUID.randomUUID() in the ID field - this complicated my work, I wrote code that checked the name of the command and opened the activity with this command. This is not quite correct, but if you use an ID without randomness in your code, you can do a check by ID. Here is the solution I made:

```
 btnDetail.setOnClickListener {
                if (match.firstCommand == "Chelsea") {
                    val intent = Intent(context, DetailActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }else if (match.firstCommand == "Everton"){
                    val intent = Intent(context, SecondDetailActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }else if(match.firstCommand== "Brentford"){
                    val intent = Intent(context, ThirdDetailActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
```